# Dynamic Elements not working ASP c#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net

I am trying to add dynamic HTML elements from the code behind file on page load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        for (int i = 98; i < 123; i++)
        {
            LinkButton btn = new LinkButton();

            Char temp = Convert.ToChar(i);

            btn.Attributes.Add("onclick", "clicked");
            btn.Attributes.Add("ID", "'" + temp + "'");
            btn.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
            btn.Text = temp.ToString().ToUpper();
            letter.Controls.Add(btn); //Letter is an id of div element

        }
    }
```

The onclick event doesnt fire

Comment: Just note that the `Attributes` property of LinkButtons are **not** server side properties, but attributes that are rendered to the browser. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.attributes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the event like below and see.
btn.lick += new System.EventHandle(clicked);